# Cannot Execute Certain Commands Over SSH

Tags: ssh

I have placed a batch file called "CrackHash.bat" in my system32 directory on my Windows computer acting as a server with freeSSHD installed. I can run this batch file just fine through the cmd window on my Windows computer.

I then connect to my Windows computer using SSH, get to the virtual command line ("C:\windows\system32>") and next try to type the exact same command ("CrackHash.bat") and I get the error:

```
'CrackHash.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: did u set path before?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `.\CrackHash.bat` or explicitly define the full path to the batch file. I suspect freeSSHD is not honoring executable expressions at the command line.